# WPF Toolkit Chart - Custom tooltip - show complex dependent value

Tags: wpf, templates, charts, tooltip, toolkit

I have the following chart:

```
<cht:Chart ...>
    <cht:Chart.Series>
        <cht:LineSeries Name="LineSeries" Title="a"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceCollection}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True"
            DataPointStyle="{DynamicResource SmallPointStyle}">
       </cht:LineSeries>
   </cht:Chart.Series>
</cht:Chart>
```

And the DataPointStyle:

```
<Style TargetType="cht:LineDataPoint"> 
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="DependentValueStringFormat" Value="{}{0:0.00}"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="SmallPointStyle" TargetType="cht:LineDataPoint" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type cht:LineDataPoint}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
</Style>
```

The source collection is a list of KeyValuePair.
The application works fine.

I encountered a problem because i want to use a collection of KeyValuePair> where doubleA is the data extracted and the doubleB is a normalised value of doubleA, based on a range. so i need to change the LineSeries to be:

```
<cht:Chart ...>
    <cht:Chart.Series>
        <cht:LineSeries Name="LineSeries" Title="a"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value.Value}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceCollection}"
        IsSelectionEnabled="True"
        DataPointStyle="{DynamicResource SmallPointStyle}">
       </cht:LineSeries>
    </cht:Chart.Series>
</cht:Chart>
```

It works as i expected, but i need to show in the tooltip the real value (Value.Key), not the DependentValue. is there anyway to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/05/19/chart-tweaking-made-easy-how-to-make-four-simple-color-tooltip-changes-with-silverlight-wpf-charting.aspx) for one possible solution.

You find the LineSeries data point style that you have to override [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18791#507649).
However, keep in mind that when you override the template you will not get any random colors anymore.

Good luck!